# Auto Resizable Text Background in Unity or how create messager in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I want to develop a messenger application. I have successfully implemented sending and receiving messages using ChatGPT, but the background size is always the same width

[image].

I want to know how to make the background of the message scale dynamically to fit the text both in width and height. Like that:

[image]

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html

Answer (score 0):

public Text txt;
public Image txtBox;

void Update()
{
txtBox.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(txt.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x, txt.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);
}

Try this :)